# Choose the correct passive form

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Please keep the door shut.

1. You are requested to **shut** the door.
2. You are requested to **keep** the door **shut**.

Who taught her such yoga practices?

1. By whom **she was** taught such yoga practices?
2. By whom **was she** taught such yoga practices?

Please support your answers with reasons or rules.

Comment: SE doesn't do your homework. Make your own choices, support with your own reasons and the rules that you know, and we can verify.  In other words, you need to show the effort beyond re-typing the question from your assignment.

Comment: and since you didn't, my answer only points you toward how to think about this.

Answer (score -1):

In your first set, both renderings are passive and grammatically proper, but one of them is semantically different from the active form.

In your second set, it's a simple matter of which one has proper *inversion* to form it as a question.

Comment: in the first set of sentences, none of them is a transformation of the active voice into passive voice. It is actually a transformation of direct speech into indirect speech - which is a completely different topic. Additionally, it is not clear what the expectation is from the exercise.